# How to open camera in an OS 4.2.2 in android

Tags: android, camera

i used many codes and all work on 4.0 but jelly bean Os did not support any code

```
 try
                     {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);        
                     }
                  catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
                    //display an error message
    //                  String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";
                     Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
                     toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                     toast.show();

                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code in your onCreate or on click of a button

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);



private void startActivityForResult(Intent data, int requestCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  

     Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
     yourActivity.pictureImg.setImageBitmap(photo);
 }  

 if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {  
     Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
     //OI FILE Manager
     filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();
     //MEDIA GALLERY
     selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri); 
     photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
     yourActivity.pictureImg.setImageBitmap(photo);

 }  
}
```

Comment: thanx for response and i used your code only find crash message "Unfortunately camera has closed"

Comment: i made many app related camera but my code is not working in jelly bean bro

Comment: Restart your mobile and try it again.

Comment: I have added the same code. It works fine on all the versions.

Comment: i checked but same response from jelly bean OS 4.2.2 and its run fine in ICECREAM 4.0 BRO

Comment: set <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> in your manifest file
and set your project to api level 16 from properties -> android

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27846/discussion-between-vabhavsingh-and-patilsagar)

Answer (score 0):

i think you have forgot to add permission  in the manifest file i have no idea about Os but in android it is like it

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```